# Instance of bulk downvote?

Tags: discussion

[image]

Looks like someone had a bad day.... I'm not worried about this whatsoever, more concerned with others if this happened to them? Did someone get out of bed on the wrong side or is this just par for the course?

Comment: A quick check doesn't give me any more info than you have. The timeline makes it look suspicious. These things do happen, best not to spend too much time wishing about it. I assume the votes will be cancelled by automated process shortly.

Comment: Yeah not worried mate - more concerned if it was affecting anyone else.